Abnormally poor WiFi performance on Ubuntu 24.04 under interference with Intel Wireless-AC
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a Dell Precision 5540 laptop, and have observed exceptionally poor (0.1x) WiFi performance compared to other devices on the same network, and also compared to the Windows OS installed on the same laptop.
The problem seems to be correlated with high levels radio interference - it is very noticeable on the 2.4 GHz bands which are highly contended where I live. However, Windows and other devices (like my iPhone) seem to able to cope with the noisy signal, but Ubuntu 24.04 can barely use it at all. When I look at the system logs (journalctl), I see a lot CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE lines which suggests to me that Ubuntu 24.04 or its WiFi driver uses some kind of transmission/reconnect logic that is exceptionally ill-adapted to these kinds of network conditions.
wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-51 noise=9999 txrate=144400

The 5 GHz band is less contended where I live, and Ubuntu 24.04 can use the 5 GHz WiFi signal, although performance is still about one-third of what it is on other devices, and on Windows. However most of the public WiFi networks I use are 2.4 GHz networks, which means Ubuntu is unusable in these locations.
Because the WiFi works fine when booting Windows on the same laptop, I doubt this is a hardware issue and I suspect Ubuntu 24.04 just ships with a really bad WiFi driver.
My WiFi card is:
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 5(802.11ac) Wireless-AC 9x6x [Thunder Peak] [8086:2526] (rev 29)

My question is how do I find and install a better WiFi driver for this card?
